# How to prevent IIS from killing the session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, iis

I have deployed a web application on IIS. Its working perfectly on local host but when I deploy it at the IIS it kills the session before going to the next page.

here is my web.config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <sessionState timeout="60"  />
</system.web>
```

How can I prevent IIS from kill the session?

Comment: The [session state timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx) just says that a single session will expire in the specified number of minutes, 60 in your case. Does it happen on all pages? Perhaps the session cookie cannot be written?

Comment: yes, this happen for every page

Comment: Is the site load balanced across multiple servers?

Comment: ah this is the problem.. Site is balanced and session is not! this causes random session exiring.. session exists just in the server that generates it!

Comment: Since this got closed on you I can't post it as an answer, but see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/httpcontext/archive/2012/06/22/shared-session-state-in-a-iis6-and-iis7-web-farm.aspx